# Evaluate $\int_{C}\frac{\sin\pi(z+1)+\cos\pi z}{(z-1)(z-2)}dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

> $$\int_{C}\frac{\sin\pi(z+1)+\cos\pi z}{(z-1)(z-2)}dz\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,C:|z|=4$$

My try:

Applying Cauchy's Integral formula

$$2\pi i\bigg[\frac{\sin\pi(z+1)+\cos\pi z}{z-1}\bigg]_{z=2}+2\pi i\bigg[\frac{\sin\pi(z+1)+\cos\pi z}{z-2}\bigg]_{z=1}=2\pi i+2\pi i=4\pi i$$

> My attempt is correct?

Comment: Don't the question in the title and the one you have solved seem different?

Comment: It is because Cauchy's formula

Comment: No no, the one in the title has $(z-1)(z-2)$ in denominator, while in your work, the denominator is $(z-1)(z-3)$.

Comment: ohh yes, stupid mistake, I will edit

Comment: Looks good to me